# Unable to send data using POST or GET from Arduino to MySQL via CytronWifiSheild

Tags: http, arduino, connection

I'm developing an IAQ monitoring system which consists of 5 sensors. It reads well, however I'm stuck for almost a week. I keep trying all available solutions, but I exhausted them all.

I noticed that my data sent to PHP code (which have code to submit data to MySQL - tested and ran flawlessly), can't get through. The host is OK (I'm using XAMPP), the client is OK too, but at the point of sending data, it fails.

I tried using POST method, but it also fails.

My code:

```cpp
//Libraries
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include "MQ135.h" 
#include <CytronWiFiShield.h>
#include <CytronWiFiClient.h>
#include <CytronWiFiServer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//WiFi Setting Constant
const char *ssid = "Itik Tungging";
const char *pass = "mc053002";
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1 ,242);
ESP8266Server server(80);

const char htmlHeader[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                        "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n"
                        "<html>\r\n";

//Send to mysql constants
IPAddress host(192, 168, 1, 83); //get from pc ipconfig http://192.168.1.83
//const char* host = "192.168.1.1";  (server ip)
const char* passcode = "mc053002";
const int httpPort = 80;

//MQ135 Constants
#define RZERO 879.13 
#define RLOAD 22.0
MQ135 gasSensor = MQ135(A1); 

//DHT22 Constants
#define DHTPIN 2     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
#define DHTPIN11 3 //pin for DHT11
#define DHTTYPE11 DHT11 // DHT11
DHT dht22(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino
DHT_Unified dht11(DHTPIN11, DHTTYPE11);

uint32_t delayMS;

//MQ7 CO Gas Sensor Constants
const int MQ7AOUTpin=0;//the AOUT pin of the CO sensor goes into analog pin A0 of the arduino
const int MQ7DOUTpin=8;//the DOUT pin of the CO sensor goes into digital pin D8 of the arduino

//MQ135 Variables
int val; 
int sensorPin = A1; 
int sensorValue = 0; 
float avgzero, zerob=0, avgval, valb=0, avgppm, ppmb=0;

//DHT Variables
int chk22;
float hum22;  //Stores humidity value
float temp22; //Stores temperature value
long randNumber;

//MQ7 Variables
int MQ7limit;
int MQ7value;

int count=0;
float hum11b=58.00, temp11b=22.00, hum22b=58.00, temp22b=22.00;
int MQ7valueb=54;

//Dust Sensor Variables
int measurePin = A2;
int ledPower = 12;

unsigned int samplingTime = 280;
unsigned int deltaTime = 40;
unsigned int sleepTime = 9680;

float voMeasured = 0;
float calcVoltage = 0;
float dustDensity = 0;

//Data to mySQL variable
ESP8266Client client;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht22.begin(); //begin temperature and humidity sensor
  dht11.begin();

  //MQ7 setup
  pinMode(MQ7DOUTpin, INPUT);//sets the pin as an input to the arduino

  //MQ135 setup
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT); 

  //Dust sensor setup
  pinMode(ledPower,OUTPUT);

  //WiFi Setup
  if(!wifi.begin(2, 3))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Error talking to shield"));
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.println(wifi.firmwareVersion());
  Serial.print(F("Mode: "));Serial.println(wifi.getMode());// 1- station mode, 2- softap mode, 3- both
   Serial.println(F("Start wifi connection"));
  if(!wifi.connectAP(ssid, pass))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Error connecting to WiFi"));
    while(1);
  } 
  Serial.print(F("Connected to "));Serial.println(wifi.SSID());
  Serial.println(F("IP address: "));
  Serial.println(wifi.localIP());
  wifi.updateStatus();
  Serial.println(wifi.status()); //2- wifi connected with ip, 3- got connection with servers or clients, 4- disconnect with clients or servers, 5- no wifi
  server.begin();

  //MySQL server setup
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to connect to server."));
    client.stop();
    while(true);
  }


}

void loop()
{
    delay(2000);
    count++;
    Serial.print(" No ");
    Serial.print(count);
    Serial.println(" readings. ");
    //Read DHT11 Sensor
    // Get temperature event and print its value.
    sensors_event_t event;  
    dht11.humidity().getEvent(&event);
    if (isnan(event.relative_humidity)) {
      Serial.print (" [DHT11] Humidity: ");
      Serial.print (hum11b);
    }
    else {
    Serial.print (" [DHT11] Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(event.relative_humidity);
    hum11b=event.relative_humidity;
    }
    Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");

    dht11.temperature().getEvent(&event);
    if (isnan(event.temperature)) {
      Serial.print(temp11b);
    }
    else {Serial.print(event.temperature);
      temp11b=event.temperature;
    }
    Serial.println(" *C");

    //Read DHT22 Sensor
    //Read data and store it to variables hum and temp
    hum22 = dht22.readHumidity();
    temp22 = dht22.readTemperature();
    //Print temp and humidity values to serial monitor
    if (isnan(dht22.readHumidity())) {
      Serial.print (" [DHT22] Humidity: ");
      randNumber=random(1,99);
      Serial.print (hum22b+randNumber/100);

    }
    else {
    Serial.print (" [DHT22] Humidity: ");
    Serial.print (hum22);
    hum22b=hum22;
    }
    Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
    if (isnan(dht22.readTemperature())) {
      randNumber=random(1,99);
      Serial.print(temp22b+randNumber/100);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print(temp22);
      temp22b=temp22;
    }
    Serial.println(" *C");

    //Read MQ7 Sensor
    MQ7value= analogRead(MQ7AOUTpin);//reads the analog value from the CO sensor's AOUT pin
    MQ7limit= digitalRead(MQ7DOUTpin);//reads the digital value from the CO sensor's DOUT pin
    if (isnan(MQ7value)) {
      Serial.print (" [MQ7] CO value: ");
      Serial.print (MQ7valueb);
    }
    else {
    Serial.print(" [MQ7] CO value: ");
    Serial.print(MQ7value);
    MQ7valueb = MQ7value;
    }
    Serial.print(" ppm ");
    Serial.print(" Limit: ");
    Serial.println(MQ7limit);//prints the limit reached as either LOW or HIGH (above or underneath)

    //MQ135 works
    Serial.print(" [MQ135] ");
    val = analogRead(A1); 
    Serial.print (" raw = "); 
    Serial.print (val); 
    if (valb==0) { 
     valb=val;
     avgval=val;
    }
    else {
      avgval=(val+valb)/2;
      valb=val;
    }
    Serial.print (" Average raw = ");
    Serial.print (avgval);

    float zero = gasSensor.getRZero(); 
    Serial.print (" rzero: "); 
    Serial.print (zero); 
      if (zerob==0) { 
      zerob=zero;
      avgzero=zero;
    }
    else {
      avgzero=(zero+zerob)/2;
      zerob=zero;
    }
    Serial.print (" Average rzero = ");
    Serial.print (avgzero);

    float ppm = gasSensor.getPPM(); 
    Serial.print (" ppm: "); 
    Serial.print (ppm); 
    if (ppmb==0) { 
      ppmb=ppm;
      avgppm=ppm;
    }
    else {
      avgppm=(ppm+ppmb)/2;
      ppmb=ppm;
    }
    Serial.print (" Average ppm = ");
    Serial.println (avgppm);

    //Read Dust Sensor
     digitalWrite(ledPower,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(samplingTime);

    voMeasured = analogRead(measurePin);

    delayMicroseconds(deltaTime);
    digitalWrite(ledPower,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(sleepTime);

    calcVoltage = voMeasured*(5.0/1024);
    dustDensity = 0.17*calcVoltage-0.1;

    if ( dustDensity < 0)
    {
      dustDensity = 0.00;
    }

    Serial.print(" [Dust Sensor] ");
    Serial.print(" Raw Signal Value (0-1023): ");
    Serial.print(voMeasured);

    Serial.print(" Voltage: ");
    Serial.print(calcVoltage);

    Serial.print(" Dust Density:");
    Serial.println(dustDensity);

    // Create a URL for the request. Modify YOUR_HOST_DIRECTORY so that you're pointing to the PHP file.
    String url = "/iotiaq/index.php?s1=";
    url += hum11b;
    url += "&s2=";
    url += temp11b;
    url += "&s3=";
    url += hum22b;
    url += "&s4=";
    url += temp22b;
    url += "&s5=";
    url += MQ7valueb;
    url += "&s6=";
    url += MQ7limit;
    url += "&s7=";
    url += val;
    url += "&s8=";
    url += avgval;
    url += "&s9=";
    url += zero;
    url += "&s10=";
    url += avgzero;
    url += "&s11=";
    url += ppm;
    url += "&s12=";
    url += avgppm;
    url += "&s13=";
    url += voMeasured;
    url += "&s14=";
    url += calcVoltage;
    url += "&s15=";
    url += dustDensity;
    url += "&pass=";
    url += passcode;

    // This will send the request to the server
    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.print(host);
    Serial.println(url);
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + String(host) + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    unsigned long timeout = millis();
    while (client.available() == 0) {
      if (millis() - timeout > 10000) {
        Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
        client.stop();
        return;
      }
    }

    Serial.println("");
    delay(10000); //Delay 2 sec.
}
```

And the output:

```
AT version:0.52.0.0(Jan  7 2016 18:44:24)
SDK version:1.5.1(e67da894)
compile time:Jan  7 2016 19:03:11
Mode: 1
Start wifi connection
Connected to Itik Tungging
IP address: 
192.168.1.205
2
Connecting to 192.168.1.83
 No 1 readings. 
 [DHT11] Humidity: 66.00 %, Temp: 29.00 *C
 [DHT22] Humidity: 80.80 %, Temp: 27.40 *C
 [MQ7] CO value: 711 ppm  Limit: 1
 [MQ135]  raw = 709 Average raw = 709.00 rzero: 97.06 Average rzero = 97.06 ppm: 209.25 Average ppm = 209.25
 [Dust Sensor]  Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 Voltage: 0.00 Dust Density:0.00
Requesting URL: 192.168.1.83/iotiaq/index.php?s1=66.00&s2=29.00&s3=80.80&s4=27.40&s5=711&s6=1&s7=709&s8=709.00&s9=97.06&s10=97.06&s11=209.25&s12=209.25&s13=0.00&s14=0.00&s15=0.00&pass=mc053002
>>> Client Timeout !
 No 2 readings. 
 [DHT11] Humidity: 65.00 %, Temp: 30.00 *C
 [DHT22] Humidity: 80.80 %, Temp: 27.50 *C
 [MQ7] CO value: 710 ppm  Limit: 1
 [MQ135]  raw = 708 Average raw = 708.50 rzero: 96.58 Average rzero = 96.82 ppm: 209.25 Average ppm = 209.25
 [Dust Sensor]  Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 Voltage: 0.00 Dust Density:0.00
Requesting URL: 192.168.1.83/iotiaq/index.php?s1=65.00&s2=30.00&s3=80.80&s4=27.50&s5=710&s6=1&s7=708&s8=708.50&s9=96.58&s10=96.82&s11=209.25&s12=209.25&s13=0.00&s14=0.00&s15=0.00&pass=mc053002
>>> Client Timeout !
 No 3 readings. 
 [DHT11] Humidity: 65.00 %, Temp: 29.00 *C
 [DHT22] Humidity: 80.60 %, Temp: 27.50 *C
 [MQ7] CO value: 710 ppm  Limit: 1
 [MQ135]  raw = 711 Average raw = 709.50 rzero: 96.58 Average rzero = 96.58 ppm: 210.20 Average ppm = 209.72
 [Dust Sensor]  Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 Voltage: 0.00 Dust Density:0.00
Requesting URL: 192.168.1.83/iotiaq/index.php?s1=65.00&s2=29.00&s3=80.60&s4=27.50&s5=710&s6=1&s7=711&s8=709.50&s9=96.58&s10=96.58&s11=210.20&s12=209.72&s13=0.00&s14=0.00&s15=0.00&pass=mc053002
>>> Client Timeout !
 No 4 readings. 
 [DHT11] Humidity: 67.00 %, Temp: 29.00 *C
 [DHT22] Humidity: 80.70 %, Temp: 27.50 *C
 [MQ7] CO value: 711 ppm  Limit: 1
 [MQ135]  raw = 712 Average raw = 711.50 rzero: 96.90 Average rzero = 96.74 ppm: 214.99 Average ppm = 212.59
 [Dust Sensor]  Raw Signal Value (0-1023): 0.00 Voltage: 0.00 Dust Density:0.00
Requesting URL: 192.168.1.83/iotiaq/index.php?s1=67.00&s2=29.00&s3=80.70&s4=27.50&s5=711&s6=1&s7=712&s8=711.50&s9=96.90&s10=96.74&s11=214.99&s12=212.59&s13=0.00&s14=0.00&s15=0.00&pass=mc053002
>>> Client Timeout !
```

Ask me for more information if you needed it.

Comment: You can't use one TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: I thought i\m doing pipelining HTTP which is send data in FIFO. Any suggestion regarding this matter? If im, keep open and close client, is it ok or do you have any good solution/implementation regarding multiple HTTP request problem?

p/s Did i need to cut down the data transfer from Arduino to MySQL? I thought POST will work, but not....